# Unable to investigate core files generated by programs built by GCC 4.6.x on Solaris

Tags: c, debugging, gcc, gdb, solaris

We are having trouble to debug **C/C++** program core files (the program was built by GCC 4.6.1), even with the debug version, though **file** command showed debugging information and symbols are available.

The symbol won't be human-readable in gdb at all even provisioned with correct debug executable.Any one can cast any light over this?

BTW, the core file can't analyzed by "mdb" or "adb" either. Each time **adb** is launched, a new core would be generated.

Debugging with gdb generates errors like:

```
warning: Cannot initialize thread debugging library: Debugger service failed
warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
```

Also tried building gdb from source, no luck. Added "LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libpthread.so.1" before launching gdb didn't work either ( actually the program was linked with **-lpthread**).

Comment: Is it C or C++? C++ compilation can perform name mangling

Comment: It's a program including C++ code, while I don't think name mangling bothers here.

Comment: You might take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114236/solaris-core-dump-analysis

Comment: @alk Thanks for the tips, though we have been using the toolkits (mdb/adb) in our team for over 2 years. The problem is now each time I launch adb it would generate a new core for itself in _/tmp_ folder. Seems librtld_db can't be loaded properly with GCC 4.6.

Comment: Try this article: http://www.fayewilliams.com/2013/01/31/gdb-unable-to-find-dynamic-linker-breakpoint-function/

Answer (score 0):

To receive a usable core file make sure your sources have been compiled using the `-g` option, prior to being linked into the executable.

To load the core, call:

```
gdb executable-which-the-core-was-created-from core-file
```

Comment: Also if using the GNU compiler: -ggdbX helps

Comment: @piotr: All this assumes you use `gcc` (from the same release as `gdb`).

Comment: Yes, the program was built with -g option and even tried with building gdb from source (7.3.1).